# I need help in getting a command to run at startup

Tags: arduino, startup

I'm trying to get a Raspberry pi to log the serial messages coming from an arduino, I can already do it from the terminal with the command: "ttylog -f -d /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 9600 >> log.txt"

How do I get this to run on startup to start recording as soon as I power up the Pi, I already tried to edit rc.log and crontab but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are executing the command from your PC connected to target, not from the target itself. In that case adding it to start up in target device won't help. If you are able to get data logged by executing the command mentioned in target device itself then try the solution below.

Create a script file save in /etc/as myscript.sh and set file permissions
    chmod 777 myscript.sh

Edit file /etc/rc.local , add line ./myscript.sh at bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it into your startup process like this:

put your logging script or a script that will run it in /etc/init.d/

then

```sh
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/yourStartScript
```

to make it executable followed by

```sh
sudo update-rc.d yourStartScript defaults
```

to register it